# Using Semantic Zoom in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying out released VS 2013 Update 2 and building a sample Universal Application.

As i found out, now Windows Phone supports multitouch by default, and this means new controls that previously weren't available.

I have tried to use simple Semantic zoom test

```
<SemanticZoom>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView Background="Red" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"/>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView Background="Black" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"/>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>
```

How can i make it happen on Windows Phone Emulator? Have tried the multitouch - didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SemanticZoom-control behaves different on Windows Phone 8.1 (compared to Windows 8). Instead of using multi-touch zoom to switch between the two views, you have to tap on the group header to show the ZoomedOutView. From this view, you can tap on an item to switch to its position in the ZoomedInView.

This behaviour is similar to the application list on Windows Phone. The letters a, b, c etc. are the group headers of the ZoomedInView - when you tap on one of them, you will see a list of all letters (ZoomedOutView).

Semantic"Zoom" might be a missleading name on Windows Phone...

Answer (score 1):

Besides your emulator you have a Bar in wich you will find 'Multi-Touch input':

[image]

When you choose it, then three circles will appear - you can change their position (without touching the screen) by right click and move. Left click will invoke multitouch at points you have set (for example it will zoom in/out the photo when you left click on one circle and move it without releasing button).

As I've tested it on Photo taken by Emulator - it is working.

Comment: Yes, on photo it works fine... seems like Semantic zoom is not responding to this...

Comment: @Cheese The problem probably is not with emulator but with your code - as I've tested it doesn't work on the device too.